# Create new column in the existing table that has value as other column in sql using django ORM

Tags: mysql, django

I want to add new column in existing table that cannot be null and should have value as other column in the table.

My attempt:

1. In my django app models, I have added the new field and migrated using migrations:

   `order_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)`
2. Ran the below sql query in database

   `Update order_data_table SET order_id=id`
3. Again removed *null=True* from models so as to set it as *non-nullable* field and migrated

Is there a better way to do?